# Scrambled number when access array[10000]

Tags: c++, arrays, primes, largenumber

I was looking for solution to question what is the 10001st prime number.
And i am done with the code :

```
int main() {
    long long listNumber[10001];
    long position = 1, divider = 0;

    listNumber[0] = 2;

    while(listNumber[10000] == 0) {
        divider = 0;
        listNumber[position] = listNumber[position-1] + 1;

        while(listNumber[divider] <= sqrt(listNumber[position])) {
            if(listNumber[position] % listNumber[divider] == 0) {
                listNumber[position]++;
                divider = 0;
            } else divider++;
        }

        position++;
    }

    cout << listNumber[10000] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but the output is always change, i don't know why. Can you help me to figure it out?
Thank You.

Comment: `while(listNumber[10000] == 0)` Arrays aren't automatically initialized with `0`.

Comment: I suggest learning how to use a debugger. Using that it's easy to solve the problem because you can see live how `listNumber` is uninitialized and how the whole `while(listNumber[10000] == 0) {` loop is skipped entirely.

Comment: Unlrealted but you don't actually need an array for this algorithm, since you only interested in the latest entry in the array a simple variable would suffice. Your while loop would change to `while (position <= 10000)`.

Answer (score 6):

You never initialize the array. That means its contents will be *indeterminate* and even reading that contents (like you do in the loop condition) leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to initialize the array:

```
long long listNumber[10001] = {};  // Initialize all elements to zero
```